# Creating a web service reference for dynamics ax in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, axapta

I'm trying to create a service reference in visual studio for a service that i've already made in dynamics ax.

when i enter the url i get an error message which says:

> There was an error downloading
>   'http://template.2003x86.local/MicrosoftDynamicsAXAif50/customerservice.svc?wsdl'.The
>   remote name could not be resolved: 'template.2003x86.local' Metadata
>   contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://template.2003x86.local/MicrosoftDynamicsAXAif50/customerservice.svc?wsdl'.
>
> There was no endpoint listening at
>   http://template.2003x86.local/MicrosoftDynamicsAXAif50/customerservice.svc?wsdl
>   that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect
>   address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more
>   details. The remote name could not be resolved:
>   'template.2003x86.local' If the service is defined in the current
>   solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference
>   again.

the AX2009 is installed on a virtual machine and the visual studio on my pc.
what configurations should i make and where?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your pc is not part of a domain called 2003x86.local, and your VPC has its own domain installed on it? This is crucial information.
Assuming your PC is in a different domain and 2003x86.local is just a made up domain on the VPC, you will need to have your PC know where to find 2003x86 because it won't be in your DNS.

An easy way to accomplish this is using the HOSTS file on your PC. This will allow you to tell your PC what IP address it can find template.2003x86.com
You can Google "HOSTS" file to find out how to use this. You will need to know the IP address of your VPC instance.